# Revert to revision previous to tip

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to build a script that checks the status of a web server and revert to the previous stable revision if an error occurs. Is there a way to return to the previous revision before the tip without knowing the revision number?. Something like this:

```
$ hg update --rev tip-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hg update -r -2` is the revision before the tip.  `hg update -r -1` is the last revision (the tip).

This isn't necessarily the direct ancestor of the tip, though.  Consider:

```
0--1---3
 \
  ---2
```

`tip` is rev 3.  `hg update -r -2` will select rev 2.

`hg update tip~1` selects the direct ancestor of the tip, or rev 1.

See `hg help revisions` and `hg help revsets`.

Comment: `tip^` is also equivalent to `tip~1`.

Comment: But in Windows ^ is an escape character in the console, so it needs to be `tip^^`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks, that's helpful. Is there a way to do it on the default branch for example? `hg update default -2`